I cannot seem to center the text in header
I'm having trouble with putting my header's text in the center, as I put display:block.
I am new to coding, and I saw that for a better finish it was wise to have an "inner-header"; So I did, but as the inner-header is a block, I cannot text-align: center nor align-items:center
Could someone help me?
I honestly tried everything I could think of, changing the display:block to flex, then adding right:...px, but nothing seems to correctly center the text.
should I get rid of the inner-header?
thanks in advance


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: #101010;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


.header{
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #101010;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   text-align: center;
}


.inner_header{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 60px;
}


.logo_container{
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    right: 40%;
    
}
.logo_container h1{
    color: bisque;
    font-family: "Whisper", cursive;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.logo_container p{
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: bisque;
}
.logo_container img{
    width: 119px;
    height: 111px;
    object-fit: fill;
}
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="inner_header">
      <div class="logo_container">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Céramique & Lumière</h1> 
        <p>UNIQUE CREATION PRODUCT</p>
        <p>HANDMADE</p>
        <img src="../photos/240610_ logo_1.png" alt>
      </div> 
    </div>      
  </div>
</header>




Is this what you are looking for?  Try not to use float.


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: #101010;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


.header{
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #101010;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   text-align: center;
}


.inner_header{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 60px;
}


.logo_container{
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin:0 auto;
    
}
.logo_container h1{
    color: bisque;
    font-family: "Whisper", cursive;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.logo_container p{
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: bisque;
}
.logo_container img{
    width: 119px;
    height: 111px;
    object-fit: fill;
}
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="inner_header">
      <div class="logo_container">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Céramique & Lumière</h1> 
        <p>UNIQUE CREATION PRODUCT</p>
        <p>HANDMADE</p>
        <img src="../photos/240610_ logo_1.png" alt>
      </div> 
    </div>      
  </div>
</header>




"Try not to use float" : Best CSS advice ever, only use absolutely placed elements when you need to !!
